# Reset Texture2Ds in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, reset, texture2d

I'm Having a problem with an experiment of mine. I'm trying to make a method that fuses one `Texture2D` into another `Texture2D`, then reloads the `Texture2D`, this time moving the pasted texture in a new spot. I plan to perfect upon this method in later projects where I paste in a spotlight onto a dark background to "illuminate" the scenery behind it. While I managed to make the paste-to method work perfectly, I am having some major problems with the second part of my plan. I have the pasted texture set to a `Vector2`, where the X member increases by 1 every frame, thus dragging the pasted texture along the background. However, the background doesn't reset after each frame, leaving a drag mark on the background where the previous image was. For the last half hour I've been working to cure this problem by resetting the background texture to make it clean again for when it has the other image pasted onto it.

Here is my code.

```cs
namespace CopyTest
{
    public class Image
    {
        public Texture2D Bitmap;
        public Vector2 Position;
        public String BitmapName;
        public Rectangle Viewport;
        public Color Tint = Color.White;
        public void ResetViewportDimensions()
        {
            this.Viewport = new Rectangle(this.Viewport.X, this.Viewport.Y, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch Target)
    {

    }
    public void FinalizeBitmap(ContentManager Target)
    {
        this.Bitmap = null;
        this.Bitmap = Target.Load<Texture2D>(this.BitmapName);
    }
    public Image(Vector2 Position, String BitmapName)
    {
        this.BitmapName = BitmapName;
        this.Position = Position;
    }
}

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Image Rainbow = new Image(new Vector2(0, 0), "Rainbow");
    public Image Eye = new Image(new Vector2(0, 0), "Glow");
    public Image PrintOut = new Image(new Vector2(0, 0), "Rainbow");

    public Vector2 Destination = new Vector2(100, 50);

    public void PrintTo(Image Source, Image Target, Vector2 Location)
    {
        Color[] A = new Color[Source.Bitmap.Width * Source.Bitmap.Width];
        Color[] B = new Color[Target.Bitmap.Width * Target.Bitmap.Width];

        int Y = 0;
        int X = 0;

        Source.Bitmap.GetData(A);
        Target.Bitmap.GetData(B);
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            B[(int)Location.X + X + (((int)Location.Y + Y) * Target.Bitmap.Width)] = A[i];
            X++;
            if (X == Source.Bitmap.Width)
            {
                X = 0;
                Y++;
            }
        }

        Target.Bitmap.SetData<Color>(B);
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Eye.FinalizeBitmap(Content);
        Rainbow.FinalizeBitmap(Content);
        PrintOut.FinalizeBitmap(Content);

        Eye.ResetViewportDimensions();
        Rainbow.ResetViewportDimensions();
        PrintOut.ResetViewportDimensions();
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;

        PrintOut.FinalizeBitmap(Content);



        PrintTo(Eye, PrintOut, Destination);
        Destination.Y++;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(PrintOut.Bitmap, PrintOut.Position, PrintOut.Viewport, PrintOut.Tint);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in reading up on Render Targets.  You can essentially group multiple sprites into one, in memory.  This may be useful to you, and improve your implementation.